# Custom component in Angular6 not reconized: error

Tags: angular, angular-components

I'm trying to extend a primeng (6) component but I am getting an error:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:  'p-inputMask-my' is not a
>   known element:
>    1. If 'p-inputMask-my' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>    2. If 'p-inputMask-my' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   to suppress this message.

Here is my configuration:

Decorator:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import "reflect-metadata";
import 'zone.js';

export function CustomComponent( annotation: any ) {
    return function( target: Function ) {
        var parentTarget = Object.getPrototypeOf( target.prototype ).constructor;
        var parentAnnotations = Reflect.getMetadata( 'annotations', parentTarget );
        if ( parentAnnotations ) {
            var parentAnnotation = parentAnnotations[0];
            Object.keys( parentAnnotation ).forEach( key => {
                if ( isPresent( parentAnnotation[key] ) ) {
                    // verify is annotation typeof function
                    if ( typeof annotation[key] === 'function' ) {
                        annotation[key] = annotation[key].call( this, parentAnnotation[key] );
                    } else if (
                        // force override in annotation base
                        !isPresent( annotation[key] )
                    ) {
                        annotation[key] = parentAnnotation[key];
                    }
                }
            } );
        }
        var metadata = new Component( annotation );
        Reflect.defineMetadata( 'annotations', [metadata], target );
    }

    function isPresent( obj: any ): boolean {
        return obj !== undefined && obj !== null;
    }
}
```

Custom component:

```
import { ElementRef, NgModule, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomComponent } from './custom-component.decorator';
import { InputMask } from 'primeng/inputmask';
import { DomHandler } from 'primeng/components/dom/domhandler';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@CustomComponent( {
    selector: 'p-inputMask-my',
    parent: InputMask
} )
export class InputMaskMy extends InputMask implements OnInit {

    constructor( public el: ElementRef, public domHandler: DomHandler ) {
        super( el, domHandler );
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    updateModel( e ) {
        var updatedValue = this.unmask ? this.getUnmaskedValue() : e.target.value;
        if ( updatedValue !== null || updatedValue !== undefined ) {
            this.value = updatedValue;
            console.log( this.value );
            if ( this.isCompleted() ) {
                this.onModelChange( this.value );
            }
        }
    }

}

@NgModule( {
    imports: [CommonModule],
    exports: [InputMaskMy],
    declarations: [InputMaskMy]
} )
export class InputMaskMyModule { }
```

app module:

```
import { InputMaskMyModule } from './component/input-mask-my';
@NgModule( {
    declarations: [
...
],
imports: [
InputMaskMyModule,
...
]
```

component.html:

```
<p-inputMask-my mask="9.99Ea99" characterPattern="[+-]" [(ngModel)]="rowData.achivedDetectionlimit" (onComplete)="dt.onEditComplete.emit({field: 'achivedDetectionlimit', data: rowData})"></p-inputMask-my>
```

What I've missed?

I've also noticed that the

> var parentAnnotations = Reflect.getMetadata( 'annotations', parentTarget );

always return null is it normal?

Comment: This error means you didn't `declare` the component in the module you're using it. Consider adding it to the `exports` array of your module, just in case.

Comment: And are you importing this module in the module you have an error with ?

Comment: yeh in app module:
`import { InputMaskMyModule } from './component/input-mask-my';
@NgModule( {
    declarations: [
...
],
imports: [
InputMaskMyModule,
...
]`
But still saying that it's not recognizing the selector p-inputMask-my.

Comment: And it isn't used anywhere else ? Consider running `ng serve` again, this could be your issue

Comment: No only the selector on the html template :
`<p-inputMask-my mask="9.99Ea99" characterPattern="[+-]" ...`
and the import:
import { InputMaskMyComponent } from '../component/input-mask-my.component';
in the corresponding typescript file

Comment: ng serve not solving the issue